# Connecting to external mysql database through C#/Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, mysql, web-services, security, visual-studio-2012

Whenever I try to perform a SQL query with an insert on my localhost, it works, using simple C# code with the Mysql.Data reference in visual studio.
But when I try to connect to my own database I have on a webserver, it gives me an exception:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect
>   to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Is my webserver bocking external requests from visual studio / c#? How do I open the server to allow these requests?

Thank you.

Comment: My guess, without seeing any code, would be a permissions issue or your connection string.

Answer (score 1):

I had developed one application in c# in that I had used MySQL database as back end that stored at bigrock.com. In your application their will be simple mistake in connection string. And turn off your firewall and your antivirus settings to off.

This is the right format of MySQL database connection string :-

```
string connectionString = "Server=Your_Server_Name;Uid=Your_User_Name;Database=Your_Database_Name;port=Your_Port_No;Pwd=Your_Password;Allow Zero Datetime=true";
```